# Ros Subscriber processes old message even with set buff_size

Tags: python, publish-subscribe, ros, subscriber

I am using ROS, Ubuntu 16.04 and Python3.

I have a publisher that publishes a custom message at 7.5 Hz. It contains 2 pointclouds and an image. One message has the size of around 2.8 MB, the average bandwith is 21.64 MB/s

I have a subscriber that subscribes to that topic but it has a noticeable delay even though `queue_size = 1`. While searching for this problem online I found multiple guides that say, that the reason is the buffer size. The default buffer size is apparently too small for the message. But I still get the same delay when I adjust the buffer size.

A code snippet is below:

```
def listener():
    rospy.init_node('node', anonymous=True)
    rospy.Subscriber("imgAndPoints", customMsg, cb, queue_size=1, buff_size = 2**28)
    #buff_size is 268MB
    rospy.spin()
cb(msg):
    msg_time = msg.header.stamp.to_sec()
    current_time = rospy.Time.now().to_sec()
    print("Delay is ", current_time - msg_time)
    time.sleep(2) #instead of performance intensive cb
    return
```

The delay grows from 0.008s at the first callback over 1.7s and 3.5s to 3.9 seconds and then stays there pretty consistently. It seems like the `buff_size=2**28` doesn't actually do anything. I get the same delays when I run the subscriber without the `buff_size` argument.

Comment: DId you ever find a solution for that issue? I am facing the same issue right now.

Comment: No sadly not. What i did then was instead of sending the big msg to a new node, I let the node that created the msg proces the data instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend changing the publisher's buffer size to 1.

since all messages are delivered in FIFO order,setting the queue_size to 1 is a valid approach if you want to make sure that a new published value will always prevent any older not yet sent values to be sent. This is good for, say, a sensor that only cares about the latest measurement. e.g. never send older measurements if a newer one exists.

[rospy documentation on choosing a good queue_size](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#Choosing_a_good_queue_size)